# Return index the same object detected

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am working object detection, atfter detected the output example of multidimention array below:

```
[[2433 1629 2656 1910]
 [2275  962 2538 1264]
 [2284 1191 2533 1472]
 [2303 1380 2551 1662]
 [2461 1442 2694 1732]
 [2284 1558 2533 1852]
 [2433 1261 2671 1524]
 [...................]
                      ]
```

There is a matrix [nx4], includes x, y, width, height
Now I  want to return index/data the objects that have the same class's id. How can I implement in Python or/and Numpy?

Comment: Hi, I think that the question needs clarifications. For example: What is the class id? Where is it stored? Do you want to return a list where each row contains two elements, one being the index of the row and the other the row itself?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry my define it was good. It is  I would like to explain more: Class id: recently I trained my datasets with 17 classes by id_classe from 1 to 17, and 18 is Background, there is only one name "object" and hence it distances from ID_CLASSes.  Basically, there are visualized by display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], 
                            class_names, r['scores']). Please let me know if something not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you have stored the classes in an array `classes` with shape `(n,)` so that the first row of your matrix `M` is associated with the first element of the array `classes`.

Given any class `c`, you can find all rows that fall into the class `c` using

```
classes == c
```

The corresponding rows in the matrix are given by

```
M[classes == c]
```

Comment: Manythanks for your response; I have solved it by wirtten: "r['rois'][r['class_ids'] == 'cliass_ids']" ;  class_ids from  1 to 17

Comment: Hi, allow me to point you to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Even if it sounds cold and distant, thank you messages are actually discouraged. You can always upvote a good answer and accept the best one. Bad answers, apparently, are to be ignored (and in some cases down-voted).